# How to efficiently use external API?

Tags: performance, api

I have a situation where I'm building an app that's getting information from an external API. The traffic in the app will be high, but the external API has not a very good architecture and can't handle too many requests.

In the app, there is personalized data, and it's brought from the API, which means a lot of queries have to be made through the API, so I need to limit the amount of queries to not take it down.

My ideas so far are:

- Join multiple queries into one when possible
- Cache info that's accessed frequently (I don't know exactly how to do that, I just know the concept)
- Create a software limitation for the number of queries made in a certain period of time

Any thoughts? Any idea is welcome, as well as more details that can clarify/correct my own ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it doesnt change frequently (i mean not every second), you can build a cacheserver which saves each requests result. So the first request with some specific params would go to your client's api, and the next time you provide stuff from chache only. You can kickstart you cache with some crawling, and also run a script to update the cache when you have low traffic. I guess? (identifying frequent requests is about looking at your request parameters.)
You can cache stuff with redis for example. Its a key-value store in-memory

Also if you are rendering data on clientside, you can launch your queries from the frontend on demand through a graphqlserver, Apollo batches your shit.

Comment: I don't have experience with graphQL, why would that make a difference? Also, the stock might be a problem. It's not updated every second, but wouldn't it be a problem if someone bought an item that doesn't exist anymore? Maybe I should update the stock more frequently than prices/discounts. Thanks for your reply!